# Get the root node in closure table with Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following the following closure table:

[image]

What i want is to get the rows that have no ancestors (root node).

In the picture above what i want to get is the first row only.

I tried the following DQL:

```
public function findAllRootGroups()
{
    $subQuery =  $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.depth > 0');

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c2');
    $query->where($query->expr()->notIn('c2.id', $subQuery->getDQL()));

    $roots = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    echo '<pre>'; \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($roots); echo '</pre>';die;
}
```

But it returned all rows with depth = 0.

So, how can i get the root nodes only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've to search on rows which have the same `ancestor_id`, `descendant_id` than their `id` and have a depth of 0

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.ancestorId = c.id')
        ->andWhere('c.descendantId = c.id')
        ->andWhere('c.depth = 0')
;
```

Comment: I think it also return same results.

Comment: That will select ids : 1 and 2 with your screenshot. It seems to be 2 root nodes no ?

Comment: only 1 root node.

Comment: "What i want is to get the rows that have no ancestors" why "rows" is plural ? :) So, with your sample, you don't have any logic to get what you want

Comment: In my example the root node is only one which is the first row only. Since there is no row that is the descendant_id is 1 other than the first row with 0 depth.